# Make all lowercase except text between speech marks

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

Taking this simple sample SQL:

```
WITH my_data as
    (SELECT 'XX_abc_123' label from DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'XX_SWU_541324_FFF' from DUAL)
SELECT label from MY_DATA;
```

Is there a way to write a Regular Expression in Notepad++ to make all text lower case, but to not change the case of any text between the '' marks, resulting in this:

```
with my_data as
    (select 'XX_abc_123' label from dual union all
     select 'XX_SWU_541324_FFF' from dual)
select label from my_data;
```

I have tried this:

1. Find: `([a-z])`
2. Replace: `\L$1\E`

But that makes everything lowercase:

```
with my_data as
    (select 'xx_abc_123' label from dual union all
     select 'xx_swu_541324_fff' from dual)
select label from my_data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*: `'[^']*'|([A-Z])`
*Replace With*: `(?1\L$1:$0)`

Make sure you select *Regular expression* and *Match Case*.

*Details*:

- `'[^']*'` - matches `'`, zero or more chars other than `'` and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `([A-Z])` - capture into Group 1 an ASCII uppercase letter.

The `(?1\L$1:$0)` means that the replacement is a lowercased Group 1 value if Group 1 matched, else, the replacement is the whole match.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ you might use SKIP FAIL to skip the matches for the single quote parts, and get matches for uppercase chars only.

```
'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z]
```

- `'[^']*'` Match from `'....'`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` SKIP the match
- `|` Or
- `[A-Z]` Match a single uppercase char A-Z

In the replacement use the match `$0`

```
\L$0\E
```

[image]